# PHP: echo item from array by its value instead of by its array index

Tags: php, arrays, key, echo

I have an array with two values stored for each item, the first one called `"ID"` and the second one called `"en"`. 
The ID values are unique integers and the en values are text.

Now I would like to echo a specific item from the array referring to it by its ID.

I tried the below but this goes by the index within the array so it gives me a different item than what I need.

Can someone tell me how I can **echo e.g. the item with ID = 10 instead of the item with the array index = 10** (here it currently gives me Value11 instead of Value1) ?

**My PHP:**

```
<?php echo $arr[10]["en"]; ?>
```

**The array:**

```
Array ( 
        [0] => Array ([ID] => 10 [en] => Value1 ),
        [1] => Array ([ID] => 11 [en] => Value2 ),
        [2] => Array ([ID] => 12 [en] => Value3 ),
        // ...
        [10] => Array ([ID] => 20 [en] => Value11 ),
        // ...
      )
```

Many thanks in advance, 
Mike

Comment: is it always [0] contaion ID=10 or only for example?

Comment: Thanks - this is just an example. This changes all the time which is why I want to go by my own ID since this stays the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want that when you pass any value it will check that where the value exist at `id` index of your multidimensional array and give it's `key` and it's `en` index value.

```
<?php

$array = Array ( 
        '0' => Array ('ID' => 10, 'en' => 'Value1' ),
        '1' => Array ('ID' => 11, 'en' => 'Value2' ),
        '2' => Array ('ID' => 12, 'en' => 'Value3' )
        );
function findKeyandValue($array,$value){

   foreach($array as $key=>$val){
    if($val['ID']== $value){
        echo 'key of the value pass='.$key.'and its en value is'.$val['en'].'<br>';
    }
}

}

findKeyandValue($array,10);
?>
```

Output:-  https://eval.in/382010

Comment: Thanks a lot for this as well ! This is great and works well but it seems to be very similar to the answer from splash58. Am I missing something here ?

Comment: iIt returns the key of given value and also the en value also.

Comment: Thanks for that ! This is very helpful but in this case I just need the en value. :)

Comment: it's simple remove `$key` from `echo`. and instead of `echo` put `return`

Comment: For some reason I couldn't get the other solution to work fully, perhaps due to the two dimensions in the array or I made a mistake as it always returned nothing but it worked with your suggestion so I accepted that one and voted splash's comments up. Thanks again !

Answer (score 2):

```
function FindByID($arr, $id) {
  foreach($arr as $item) {
   if ($item['ID'] === $id) return $item['en'];
  } 
  return null;
}

echo FindByID($arr, 11);
```

Comment: @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com you make my code invalid with your else. You may try. Return null must be after foreach

Comment: Then pls add `{` after foreach and after end of foreach. Else it makes your code confusing.

Comment: @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com Strange practice to vote against the program to work

Comment: @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com I can only for you :)

Comment: Dont you think current answer looks cleaner  ?

Comment: I don't like paranthesis around a single operator

Comment: Its not about your like ! What if each day new Developer comes and modifies that statement ? he may add another 10 statements in For loop if you write such confusing code and 10 statements wont have brackets. So in short avoiding brackets is **bad practice** !

Comment: I would agree with you if this was included in the syntax of the language. And so it is a matter of style and autoritet :)

Comment: @splash58: Thanks a lot for this ! This works great and is easy to understand. Big help ! :)

Comment: @splash58: Thanks ! Just one quick questios after implementing this, hope that's ok ? Do I need to declare the variable $id somewhere before the function, just to do it properly ?

Comment: 1) id is argument of function. You may use any variable or constant `$a = 10; FindByID($arr, $a);`

Comment: 2) the same about array - write the name of array you use. It is it does not matter - the different or the same name

Comment: For some reason I couldn't get this to work fully, perhaps due to the two dimensions in the array or I made a mistake as it always returned nothing but it worked with Anant's suggestion so I accepted that one and voted your comments up, hope that's ok. Sorry and thanks again for your help !

Comment: I don't see the difference between  implementation of these two solutions :) But don't worry - all is  OK :)